# Add legend to barplot with gradient using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, legend

I have plotted a data frame using seaborn where the color is based on the values in the column `"loan_status"`.

Data:

```
    Count   loan_status sub_grade
sub_grade           
A1  9729    0.971323    A1
A2  9567    0.951814    A2
A3  10576   0.941944    A3
A4  15789   0.929761    A4
```

Plotting:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
g = sns.barplot(x="sub_grade", y= "Count", order= sub_grades, data=df, palette=cm.Blues(df['loan_status']))
```

I would like to add a legend for the color gradient of this plot.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

[image]

you can create the colorbar on-the-fly like this

```py
g = sns.barplot(x='sub_grade', y = 'Count', data = df, palette = cm.Blues(df['load_status']))

plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.blues))
```